# Rows in pivot table not merging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have created the following table to illustrate what is happening

```
create table weather (
    WDate varchar(10),
    ItemCode varchar(8),
    ItemValue int,
    ItemUnits varchar(8))

insert into Weather values 
    ('2020-02-10', 'MAXTEMP', 6, 'degC'),
    ('2020-02-10', 'MINTEMP', 2, 'degC'),
    ('2020-02-10', 'RAIN', 0, 'mm'),

    ('2020-02-11', 'MAXTEMP', 5, 'degC'),
    ('2020-02-11', 'RAIN', 20, 'mm'),
    ('2020-02-11', 'MINTEMP', 1, 'degC'),

    ('2020-02-12', 'RAIN', 5, 'mm'),
    ('2020-02-12', 'MAXTEMP', 8, 'degC'),
    ('2020-02-12', 'MINTEMP', 2, 'degC')
```

The data is not always in the same order because it can come from equipment that may not be time sync'ed.  When I run the following query

```
SELECT
    [wdate] as 'Date',
    [MINTEMP] as 'Min Temp',
    [MAXTEMP] as 'Max Temp',
    [RAIN] as 'Rain'
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        weather
) rawdata
PIVOT
(
    min(ItemValue)
    FOR ItemCode IN ([MINTEMP], [MAXTEMP], [RAIN])
) pitem
ORDER BY WDate
```

I get

```
WDate       Min Temp  Max Temp  Rain
2020-02-10  2         6         NULL
2020-02-10  NULL      NULL      0
2020-02-11  1         5         NULL
2020-02-11  NULL      NULL      20
2020-02-12  2         8         NULL
2020-02-12  NULL      NULL      5
```

I can't figure out why the Rain data doesn't end up on the same row as the Min and Max Temp.  I was expecting

```
WDate       Min Temp  Max Temp  Rain
2020-02-10  2         6         0
2020-02-11  1         5         20
2020-02-12  2         8         5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must "FEED" the pivot with the minimum number of columns.  Notice the `ItemUnits` is missing from the sub-select `rawdata`

**Example**

```
SELECT
    [wdate] as 'Date',
    [MINTEMP] as 'Min Temp',
    [MAXTEMP] as 'Max Temp',
    [RAIN] as 'Rain'
FROM
(
    Select WDate
          ,ItemCode
          ,ItemValue 
      from Weather
) rawdata
PIVOT
(
    min(ItemValue)
    FOR ItemCode IN ([MINTEMP], [MAXTEMP], [RAIN])
) pitem
ORDER BY WDate
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Min Temp    Max Temp    Rain
2020-02-10  2           6           0
2020-02-11  1           5           20
2020-02-12  2           8           5
```

Comment: I was going to raise a separate question on ItemUnits.  So basically I should specify the columns I am using and leave out the ones that I am not using.

Comment: @cup  BINGO!!  you got it :)